# Angular 9 implement canActive: Observable<boolean>, catchError failed ts check

Tags: angular, rxjs6

I use angular9, rxjs6 and implement canActive: Observable 
But I got an error when use catchError, like this:

[image]

How can I fix this?

I tried update to: but it still not work.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

another way to solve canActivate function in your guard is only use subscribe because i think use map in this situation is wrong

```
  this.yourService.subscribe(
    (r) => {
      //your code
      return true;
    },
    (error: any) => {
      return false;
    }
  );
```

Comment: my function need return Observable<boolean> to waiting check

Comment: my friend you can add another type to your canActivate function to cover boolean response because in your situation problem is solved by boolean like this one: 

canActivate( route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean